# Error with the AmazonDynamoDBClient - getCredentialsProvider() function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I am working on the Android app and there is a need to use the AWS DynamoDB in my android app. I completed all the process of 
1) Amplify
2) IAM and the cognito Identity pool

When I tried to initialise the AmazonDynamoDBClient I am getting the error "Cannot resolve getCredentialsProvider()". I am a beginner in using the AWS Products and its functionalities.Please suggest me some solutions to overcome from this error.

I share the code below for your reference, and let me know what changes I can make to overcome this error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AWSAppSyncClient mAWSAppSyncClient;
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {

                // Add code to instantiate a AmazonDynamoDBClient
                AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
                dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
                        .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
                        .awsConfiguration(
                                AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .build();

            }
        }).execute();
 }
}
```

Also I have used the dependencies and the implementation as well in the app/build.gradle

Comment: It looks like this is missing some code, and some detail. Can you double check that you've posted the complete snippet, @Nishanth?